# How to allow more than one image upload on django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Currently I have a pictures model, that allows an image upload per class product (Foreign key).

However I would like to upload more than one image per product

Below shows my models.py for Class picture.

```
def get_image_filename(instance,filename):
    id = instance.product.id
    return "picture_image/%s" % (id)

def path_and_rename(instance, filename):
    upload_to = 'images'
    ext = filename.split('.'[-1])
    if instance.pk:
        filename = '{}.{}'.format(instance.pk, ext)
    else:
        filename = '{}.{}'.format(uuid4().hex, ext)
    return os.path.join(upload_to, filename)

class Picture(models.Model):
    product_pic = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True,upload_to=path_and_rename)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL )
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
```

How does one allow more than one image upload on django?

Comment: You can already, you simply should create multiple `Picture` objects where the `product` field refers to the *same* `Product`.

Comment: You can use *formsets* to make a form that allows uploading in bulk: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets

Comment: Cool, can you show an example on how that would work in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does one allow more than one image upload on django?

You already *can*. Indeed, you can construct multiple `Picture` objects for the same `Product`. For example:

```
myproduct = Product.objects.first()
Picture.objects.create(product=my_product, product_pic=request.FILES['image1'])
Picture.objects.create(product=my_product, product_pic=request.FILES['image2'])
```

Here we thus construct two `Picture` objects that refer to the *same* `Product`.

You can make use of *formsets* to render the form for a `Picture` multiple times. For example:

```
from django.forms import inlineformset_factory
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from app.models import Product, Picture

def my_view(request, product_pk):
    PictureFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Product, Picture, fields=('product_pic',))
    product = Author.objects.get(pk=product_pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = PictureFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=product)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            return redirect('name-of-some-view')
    else:
        formset = PictureFormSet(instance=product)
    return render(request, 'some_template.html', {'formset': formset})
```

and in your template you then render this with:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="{% url 'name-of-view' product_pk=formset.instance.pk %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset }}
</form>
```

Comment: Great, I'll try it out and keep you informed